# How to run the same code on different tabs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a bit of code which runs down a table and sends emails when an item reaches its expiry date.

```
function expiryAlert() {
  // get the spreadsheet object
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // set the first sheet as active
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  // fetch this sheet
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // figure out what the last row is
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
  // is the headers, so start with row 4
  var startRow = 3;

  // days left column
  var range = sheet.getRange(7,4,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var days_open_values = range.getValues();

  // item number column
  range = sheet.getRange(7, 1, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
  var item_number_values = range.getValues();

  //Now grab the description number
  range = sheet.getRange(7, 2, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
  var description_values = range.getValues();

  //Now grab the email addresses
  range = sheet.getRange(7, 7, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
  var emailAddress_values = range.getValues();

  //Now grab the alert days value
  range = sheet.getRange(2, 2);
  var alert_days_values = range.getValues();

  //Grab the sheet title
  range = sheet.getRange(1,1);
  var title_values = range.getValues();

  //Grab the extra alert message
  range = sheet.getRange(3,2);
  var alert_message_values = range.getValues();

  var msg = "";

  // Loop over the days left values
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var days_open = days_open_values[i][0];
    var alert_days = alert_days_values;
    if(days_open == alert_days) {

      var item_number = item_number_values[i][0];
      var description = description_values[i][0];
      var emailAddress = emailAddress_values[i][0];
      var title = title_values;
      var alert_message = alert_message_values;

      msg = msg + "This is an automated alert for "+title+"\n\nItem number "+item_number+", "+description+", is due to expire in "+days_open+" days. Please ensure it is updated or reviewed.\n\n"+alert_message+"\n\n";

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,title, msg);
    }
  }

};
```

I want to add another tab for a different shift and run the same code on that table.

How can I do that? I have googled and searched and can't find anything to help.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to delete this code:

```
// set the first sheet as active
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
```

if you want the code to run on the currently active sheet.  That line of code always gets the very first sheet tab in the spreadsheet.  The index zero `[0]` is the first sheet in the array.

If you want the code to affect the currently active sheet tab, you'll need to either manually select the sheet tab that you want the code to work on, or you'd need to have something like two different menu items that each pass the sheet name to the code.

You could get each sheet by name:

```
.getSheetByName(theSheetName)
```

If you do that, you'll need to pass the sheet name to the function.

```
function expiryAlert(theSheetName) {
```

You could have an image that looks like a button in each sheet, and the script attached would have the sheet name.   You could have a sidebar with two different buttons.  You could have a sidebar with a dropdown list of the sheet names.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar.  I am not an expert, just a struggling amateur programmer.  Your script probably produces a code.gs tab, right.  click that tab and pulldown, select make a copy.  it will create a new tab at the bottom called Copyof Code.gs.  Go into the script of  Copyof Code.gs make your required changes to the code.  Click save button.  go back to the tab in the vertical tab list on the left hand side,  (this next bit doesn't work if you select to top tabs). Select pulldown, rename  then rename to some thing meaningful.  If you are happy keeping Code.gs,  then you need to go back to the original code.gs you previously copied from select pulldown, delete.  confirm you are sure in the popup window.  This step is needed because it doesn't like tabs with the same name.  go to vertical tab name list Copyof Code.gs. select pulldown Rename then carefully select and delete Copyof leaving only Code.gs
Hit the save button then hit the run button.  Voila the new code will run. based on the code written in the lowest tab of the vertical tab list.

I have created 18 similar tabs all processing data slightly differently and there seems no way to execute a particular tab without moving it to the bottom of the tab list by this tortuous copy, rename and delete process before saving and running.  Sorry for the detail, hope it makes sense.  happy if anyone knows an easier way, regards Des

Comment: The behavior you experience is because only a single function can have the same name as any other function in n the same namespace. All .gs files in the same Script Project share a namespace. What that means is if you declare `function foo()` multiple times, only the last-read definition is used - any previous definitions are shadowed by the most recent one.